# Attempt to deference null object and view limit exceeded above 135kb

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:page id="uploadImagePage" standardController="Service_Partner_compliance__c" extensions="Contactsextension">

    <style type="text/css">
        .pic {
            background-color : #F3F3EC;
            border:2px solid #E3DEB8;
            height:100px;
            /*margin :15px auto;*/
            padding:5px;
            width:100px;
            margin:20px;
        }
        .buttons , .input { 
            margin:20px; 
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function verifyNameLength(){
            var textVal = document.getElementsByName('uploadImagePage:uploadAttachment:newAttach:inputFile:file')[0].value;

            if( textVal != "" )     {
                var browser = navigator.userAgent;
                var fileName = textVal;

                if( browser.search( 'MSIE' ) > 0 ) {
                    var index       = textVal.lastIndexOf( '\\' );
                    fileName        = textVal.substring( index +1);
                } 

                if( fileName.length < 70) {
                    return true;
                };
            };
            if( textVal == "" )     {
                alert( 'Please select an image to upload' );
            } else {
                alert( 'The file name must be 70 characters maximum' );
            }
            document.getElementById('uploadImagePage:uploadAttachment').reset();
            return false;
        }
    </script>

    <apex:form id="uploadAttachment">

        <apex:outputpanel styleClass="pic" id="image" layout="block">
             <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PictureUploader, '/images/unknownperson.jpg')}" rendered="{!NOT( hasPicture )}" height="100" width="100"/>
             <apex:image value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!file.Id}" rendered="{!hasPicture}" height="100" width="100"/>
        </apex:outputpanel>

        <div class="input">
            <b>1. Select the File</b> : Type the path of the file or click the Browse button to find the file.<br/>
            <apex:inputFile value="{!newAttach.Body}" 
                id="newAttach" 
                styleclass="newAttach" 
                contentType="{!newAttach.ContentType}" 
                filename="{!newAttach.Name}" 
                fileSize="{!newAttach.BodyLength}" />
            <br/>
            <apex:outputText value="{!error}" escape="false" styleClass="errorMsg"/> 
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <b>2. Click the "Upload" button or "Delete" button in order to delete the current picture </b><br/>
            <apex:commandButton id="Accept" action="{!uploadAction}" value="Upload" onclick="return verifyNameLength();"></apex:commandButton>
            <apex:commandButton id="Delete" action="{!deleteAction}" value="Delete" rendered="{!hasPicture}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the current image?')"></apex:commandButton>
            <apex:commandButton id="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"></apex:commandButton>
        </div> 

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**controller::**

```
public with sharing class Contactsextension{

    private final Integer MAX_SIZE          = 131072; // 128Kb
    private final Integer MAX_LENGTH_NAME   = 71;
    private final String  ERROR_NO_SAVE     = 'Please select a file to upload and try again.';
    private final String  ERROR_IMG_TYPE    = 'The image must be .jpg, .gif or .png';   


   transient  private Set<String> imagesTypes         = new Set<String> {'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/gif'};
   transient  private Set<String> notAllowedTypes     = new Set<String> {'application/octet-stream'};

    transient public Attachment   newAttach           { set; get; }
    transient public Attachment   file                { set; get; }
    private String      parentId            { set; get; }
    public String       postAction          { set; get; }
    public String       error               { set; get; }
    public Boolean      hasPicture          { set; get; }

    /**
    * Constructor
    */ 
    public Contactsextension( ApexPages.StandardController stdController ){

        this.parentId       = stdController.getId();
        this.hasPicture     = false;
        this.newAttach      = new Attachment();
        this.error          = '';

        List<Attachment> attList = [ Select ParentId, Name, Id, ContentType, BodyLength From Attachment where ParentId =: this.parentId and name = 'Contact Picture' limit 1];
        if( attList.size() > 0 ){
            this.file               = attList.get( 0 );
            this.hasPicture         = true;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Upload action, store the file or replace if exists
    * @return thePage
    */
    public PageReference uploadAction(){

        PageReference thePage = new PageReference( '/'+ parentId );
        thePage.setRedirect( true );
        if( this.validate() ){
            return ( this.saveCurrentPicture() ) ? thePage : null;
        }
        else{
            this.newAttach = new Attachment();
            return null;
        }
    }


    /**
    * Save the New Attachment as Contact Picture
    * @return : boolean
    */
    public Boolean saveCurrentPicture(){
        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        try{
            delete [ Select Id From Attachment where ParentId =: this.parentId and name = 'Contact Picture' limit 1 ];
            this.newAttach.parentId = this.parentId;
            this.newAttach.name = 'Contact Picture';
            insert this.newAttach;
            return true;
        } 
        catch( Exception e ){
            this.error += ERROR_NO_SAVE+'<br/>';
            Database.rollback( sp );
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
    * Detele action, delete the curren image
    * @return thePage
    */
    public PageReference deleteAction(){

        PageReference thePage = new PageReference( '/'+ parentId );
        thePage.setRedirect( true );
        delete this.file;
        return thePage;
    }

    /**
    * Run all verification for the file to upload
    * @return ret
    */
    private Boolean validate(){
        Boolean ret = true;
        this.error = '';
        newAttach = new Attachment();
        if( !imagesTypes.contains( newAttach.ContentType ) ){
            this.error += ERROR_IMG_TYPE+'<br/>';
            ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /**
    * Cancel action
    * @return thePage a page reference
    */
    public PageReference cancel(){
        PageReference thePage = new PageReference( '/'+ parentId );
        thePage.setRedirect( true );
        return thePage;
    }

    /**
    * Test cases for rigth image types and a wrong type
    */
   /* public static testMethod void testImageTypes(){
        TestUtilities tu = TestUtilities.generateTest();

        ApexPages.StandardController sc;
        Contactsextension cTest;

        Contact myContact = tu.aContac;

        List<String> types = new List<String>{'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/gif'};

        Attachment tempAtt = new Attachment();

        system.Test.startTest();
            for( String aType: types ){
                sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(myContact);
                cTest = new Contactsextension( sc );
                cTest.newAttach.Name = 'Picture-' + sc.getId();
                cTest.newAttach.Body = Blob.valueOf('String');
                cTest.newAttach.ContentType = aType;
                cTest.uploadAction();

                cTest.newAttach.Body = Blob.valueOf('String');

                System.assert( cTest.newAttach.name == 'Contact Picture', 'Name not equals' );
                System.assert( cTest.newAttach.ContentType == aType, 'Types not equals' );

            }

            sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(myContact);
            cTest = new Contactsextension( sc );
            cTest.newAttach.Name = 'Picture-' + sc.getId();
            cTest.newAttach.Body = Blob.valueOf('String');
            cTest.newAttach.ContentType = 'image/YYY';
            cTest.uploadAction();
            System.assert( cTest.error == 'The image must be .jpg, .gif or .png<br/>', 'Error in error message.' + cTest.error);

            cTest = new Contactsextension( sc );
            cTest.uploadAction();

        system.Test.stopTest();
    } 

    /**
    *Test upload picture with no picture at the start.
    *
    */
  /*  public static testMethod void testNoPicture(){
        TestUtilities tu = TestUtilities.generateTest();

        system.Test.startTest();
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController( tu.aContac );
        Contactsextension cTest = new Contactsextension( sc );
        cTest.newAttach.Name = 'Picture-' + sc.getId();
        cTest.newAttach.Body = Blob.valueOf('String');
        cTest.newAttach.ContentType = 'image/jpeg';
        cTest.uploadAction();

        Attachment attUploaded = [ SELECT name, parentId, body, ContentType FROM Attachment WHERE parentId =: sc.getId() AND name = 'Contact Picture'];
        System.assert( attUploaded != null, 'No attachment uploaded.' );
        System.assert( attUploaded.name == 'Contact Picture', 'Name not equals.' );
        System.assert( attUploaded.Body.toString() == Blob.valueOf('String').toString(), 'Bodys not equals.' );
        System.assert( attUploaded.ContentType == 'image/jpeg', 'Types not equals.' );


        // Replace string
        sc = new ApexPages.StandardController( tu.aContac );
        cTest = new Contactsextension( sc );
        cTest.newAttach.Name = 'Picture-' + sc.getId();
        cTest.newAttach.Body = Blob.valueOf('Other String For Replacement');
        cTest.newAttach.ContentType = 'image/png';
        cTest.uploadAction();

        attUploaded = [ SELECT name, parentId, body, ContentType FROM Attachment WHERE parentId =: sc.getId() AND name = 'Contact Picture'];
        System.assert( attUploaded != null, 'No attachment uploaded.' );
        System.assert( attUploaded.name == 'Contact Picture', 'Name not equals.' );
        System.assert( attUploaded.Body.toString() == Blob.valueOf('Other String For Replacement').toString(), 'Bodys not equals.' );
        System.assert( attUploaded.ContentType == 'image/png', 'Types not equals.' );


        Id stroringAttIdForRetreve = cTest.newAttach.id;
        cTest = new Contactsextension( sc );
        cTest.deleteAction();
        List<Attachment> attUploadedList = [ SELECT id FROM Attachment WHERE id =: stroringAttIdForRetreve ];

        System.assert( attUploadedList.size() == 0, 'Attachment not deleted !!!' );

        system.Test.stopTest();    
    }

    /**
    * Code coverage for cancel action
    */
 /*  public static testMethod void testCancelAction(){
        TestUtilities tu = TestUtilities.generateTest();

        system.Test.startTest();
            ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController( tu.aContac );
            Contactsextension cTest = new Contactsextension( sc );
            cTest.cancel();         
            System.assert( cTest.cancel() != null, 'Some error occurs with PageReference Method is called' );
        system.Test.stopTest();
    }*/
}
```

Comment: FYI for don't need system infront of start / stop test

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchaneg user16775, it helps us to understand your questions if you focus them on a single, specific issue (view state or null reference. Having a lot of code also makes it hard for us to really see what is going on, would you be able to remove all parts of the code that are not necessarily related to what your question is about ?  Doing so in your actual code will also help you to debug and gain insight into what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

After inserting the attachment make the attachment null. This prevents view state from falling apart. 
In your save method edit this.

```
insert this.newAttach;
this.newAttach=null;
return true;
```